# invalidArgumentError: when i upload file using google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, file-upload, invalid-argument

I am trying to upload the file "pdf " to google drive through google app script,  but I get an error when I click the button. Also, I wanted to use the array bytes but I don't know how to do because without the array bytes I must disable the chrome v8.

Error message :

> 2495449455-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__ar.js:56 Uncaught
> InvalidArgumentError: Failed due to illegal value in property: 0

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
                <base target="_self">
                <?!=include('css');?>

    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />


    <title>  PDF Collector</title>

      <div align="center">
      <p><img   class="responsive-img   offset-m3 s12  "
       src=""></p>
     </div>

</head>

<body>
<div  id="msg"  class="col m6 offset-m3 s12" align="center" style='color: red' > 
<div>

            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col m6 offset-m3 s12   ">
            
            
               <div class="input-field">
                    <input placeholder="Your Id" id="employeeId" type="number" class="validate" required pattern ="^\d{10}$" >
                    <label class="active" for="id">Your Id</label>
                </div>

      
                <div class="input-field">
                    <input placeholder="Your name" id="fullname" type="text" class="validate" disabled >
                    <label class="active" for="name">Full Name</label>
                </div>


                 <div class="file-field input-field">
                     <div class="btn">
                      <span>File</span>
                     <input type="file" name="myFile">
                             </div>
                  <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                   <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
                   </div>
                  </div>
            
                
                <button id="btn" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit"
                    name="action" > Submit
                    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                  </button>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

        </div>

    </div>
    
   
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
              
    <?!=include('js');?>

</body>
</html>
```

JS Code

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',
        function(e){
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).uploadFiles(this.parentNode)
        })
        
        function onSuccess(data){
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Thanks for Uploading";
        }
```

This the function in .gs

```
function uploadFiles(data)
{
 var file = data.myFile;
 var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(collected-Pdf);
  Logger.log(folder);
 var createFile = folder.createFile(file);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the line `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).uploadFiles(this.parentNode)` I don't think you can just send an entire html node to the server, it probably tried to parse it as a json or something and failed, pretty much the most you can do is send the file itself

`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).uploadFiles(document.getElementsByClassName("myFile").files[0])`

Plus the parent node of the button isn't the input element anyway, yet you are trying to access the `.myFile` element of it but I don't think class names are added to the server like that, but even if they were that would only be accessing the input element itself not the `.files` property of it

Comment: Yeah, google apps script does not have any notion of DOM or Web APIs being server-side, so sending over anything that would not be valid in a plain JavaScript environment will fail...

Comment: bluejayke  ,  when I used the getElementsByClassName("myFile").files[0] i got  this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> . so I changed it to getelementByid and I got error in uploadFiles the error , uncaught  at uploadFiles (uploadFunction:3)  . I checked the chrome consol and I found the error is that  function ue(a, b) {
        b = Error(b);
        b.name = a;
        return b

Comment: why it cannot read the myFile property . each time I click the button I get  Uncaught  at uploadFiles (uploadFunction:2) line number 2 is   var file = data.myFile; . which it should be defined  in <input type="file" name="myFile">

Comment: @nassaf it seems the button was also given the same class as the input tag. On the `<input>` field add an ID then use getElementById("ID").files[0] instead

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer after dividing the code and test each code one by one. It turned out that the name="action and waves-effect are the reason to stop the code from running. I don't know why but it is working now after removing them from html.

```
<button id="btn" class="btn  waves-light" type="submit"
                    " > Submit
                    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                  </button>
```